# Grouping and sum the value for every 5min / resampling the data for 5min with string values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pandas-resample

I want to sum the value of each gender for every 5 min timestamp.

Main Table:-

```
Time   Gender  value

10:01  Male      5
10:02  Female    1
10:03  Male      5
10:04  Male      5
10:05  Female    1
10:06  Female    1
10:07  Male      5
10:08  Male      5
10:09  Male      5
10:10  Male      5
```

Required Result:-

```
Time   Gender  value
10:00  Male     15
10:00  Female   2
10:05  Male     20
10:05  Female   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert to `TimeDelta`, `floor` the result, and use it to `groupby`+`agg`:

```
t = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']+':00')
(df
 .groupby([t.dt.floor('5min'), 'Gender']) 
 .agg({'value': 'sum'})
 .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
             Time  Gender  value
0 0 days 10:00:00  Female      1
1 0 days 10:00:00    Male     15
2 0 days 10:05:00  Female      2
3 0 days 10:05:00    Male     15
4 0 days 10:10:00    Male      5
```

###### matching the provided output

To match your provided output, it needs a few more things.

- subtracting one minute to floor '00:05:00' on '00:00:00'
- converting back to string

```
t = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']+':00').sub(pd.to_timedelta('1min'))

(df
 .groupby([t.dt.floor('5min'), 'Gender']) 
 .agg({'value': 'sum'})
 .reset_index()
 .assign(Time=lambda d: (pd.to_datetime(0)+d['Time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M'))
)
```

output:

```
    Time  Gender  value
0  10:00  Female      2
1  10:00    Male     15
2  10:05  Female      1
3  10:05    Male     20
```

###### variant

```
t = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']+':00').sub(pd.to_timedelta('1min'))
(df.assign(Time=t.dt.floor('5min').astype(str).str[-8:-3])
   .groupby(['Time', 'Gender'])
   ['value'].sum().reset_index()
)
```

Comment: Can you update your post with this alternative? `df.assign(Time=pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'] + ':00').dt.floor('5min').astype(str).str[-8:-3]).groupby(['Time', 'Gender'])['value'].sum().reset_index()`

Comment: Probably a DV because OP does not show some effort to solve his problem. As usual :( +1 for the answer

Comment: Can anyone help me on this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71161977/17841241